# Annotations not loading properly

Tags: objective-c, swift

Im trying to load my annotations using JPSThumbnail on swift. With the code below for some reason whenever It loads, it loads my annotations with the usual red pin. I have no clue in objective C so I dont know what should be done? What is missing in my code, am I appending right to the array?
[JPSThumnail Github](https://github.com/jpsim/JPSThumbnailAnnotation)

JPSThumbnailAnnotation:

```
 + (instancetype)annotationWithThumbnail:(JPSThumbnail *)thumbnail {
return [[self alloc] initWithThumbnail:thumbnail];
 }

 - (id)initWithThumbnail:(JPSThumbnail *)thumbnail {
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    _coordinate = thumbnail.coordinate;
    _thumbnail = thumbnail;
}
return self;
 }

 - (MKAnnotationView *)annotationViewInMap:(MKMapView *)mapView {
if (!self.view) {
    self.view = (JPSThumbnailAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:kJPSThumbnailAnnotationViewReuseID];
    if (!self.view) self.view = [[JPSThumbnailAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:self];
} else {
    self.view.annotation = self;
}
[self updateThumbnail:self.thumbnail animated:NO];
return self.view;
 }

 - (void)updateThumbnail:(JPSThumbnail *)thumbnail animated:(BOOL)animated {
if (animated) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.33f animations:^{
        _coordinate = thumbnail.coordinate; // use ivar to avoid triggering setter
    }];
} else {
    _coordinate = thumbnail.coordinate; // use ivar to avoid triggering setter
}

[self.view updateWithThumbnail:thumbnail];
 }
```

My Swift Code:

```
func annotations() -> [JPSThumbnailAnnotation] {
    var annotations: [JPSThumbnailAnnotation] = []
    let pointData = NSData(contentsOfFile: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("1000", ofType: "geojson")!)
    let points = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(pointData!,
        options: nil,
        error: nil) as! NSDictionary
    for point in points["glimps"] as! NSArray {
        var a = JPSThumbnail()
        a.image = UIImage(named: "empire.jpg")
        a.title = "Empire State Building"
        a.subtitle = "NYC Landmark"
        var lat = (point as! NSDictionary)["latitude"] as! CLLocationDegrees
        var lon = (point as! NSDictionary)["longitude"] as! CLLocationDegrees

        a.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon)
        a.disclosureBlock = { println("selected Empire") }
        var a1: JPSThumbnailAnnotation = JPSThumbnailAnnotation(thumbnail: a)
        annotations.append(a1)
    }
    return annotations
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {
    return (annotation as? JPSThumbnailAnnotationProtocol)?.annotationViewInMap(mapView)
}
```